# MongoDB aggregation to update more than one collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

was wondering if it's possible to create such aggregation that could modify three collection in one go?

For example imagine that we have these collections:

**MasterCollection**:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId;
}
```

**CollectionOne**:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId;
  _masterCollectionId: ObjectId;
  _parentId: ObjectId;
  _title: String;
  _displayTitle: String;
}
```

**CollectionTwo**:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId;
  _masterCollectionId: ObjectId;
  _parentId: ObjectId;
  _displayTitle: String;
}
```

**CollectionThree**:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId;
  _masterCollectionId: ObjectId
  _parentId: ObjectId;
  _displayTitle: String;
}
```

**Aggregation to lookup**:

```
[
  {
    $match: {
        _id: new ObjectId("618552b66f82e69572e9bf10")
     }
  }, 
  {
    $lookup: {
        from: "CollectionOne",
        let: {
            "collectionOneId": "$_id"
        },
        pipeline: [{
            "$match": {
                "$expr": {
                    "$eq": ["$_parentId", "$$collectionOneId"]
                }
            }
        }, {
            "$lookup": {
                "from": "CollectionTwo",
                "let": {
                    "collectionTwoId": "$_id"
                },
                "pipeline": [{
                    "$match": {
                        "$expr": {
                            "$eq": ["$_parentId", "$$collectionTwoId"]
                        }
                    }
                }, {
                    "$lookup": {
                        "from": "CollectionThree",
                        "let": {
                            "collectionThreeId": "$_id"
                        },
                        "pipeline": [{
                            "$match": {
                                "$expr": {
                                    "$eq": ["$_parentId", "$$collectionThreeId"]
                                }
                            }
                        }],
                        "as": "CollectionThree"
                    }
                }],
                "as": "CollectionTwo"
            }
        }],
        as: "CollectionOne"

    } 
}]
```

---

With aggregation above I can get all children of MasterCollection record.
In similar way I could get CollectionOne record children.

But I am thinking if there could be a way to apply changes within pipeline for each record.

For example imagine situation that there is a need to change **_masterCollectionId** for **CollectionOne** record.

If we change that property we need to update all children records (CollectionTwo / CollectionThree).

1. Would need to update targeted **CollectionOne** record.
2. Would need to update **CollectionTwo** records that points to updated **CollectionOne** record.
3. Would need to update **CollectionThree** records that points to updated records of **CollectionTwo**.

Currently, programmatically I can do a loop and update everything, it kinda works. But I think there should be better solution, probably at database layer, using MongoDB aggregations.

Can MongoDB Aggregation achieve desired result ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I think what you're after is impossible using aggregation alone like you've explained.

The MongoDB documentation states that you can pass an aggregation pipeline into an `updateMany()` call where you can perform operations on the collection within the aggregation pipeline in MongoDB 4.2 or newer.

I haven't actually tried this technique personally, but it sounds like it might do the job. Based on the documentation, you'd need to run the `updateMany()` on each collection, which is still a huge improvement on what you've got already. Check it out [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/#update-with-an-aggregation-pipeline).

Something like this:

```
await CollectionOne.updateMany(
    { _masterClientId: <oldID> },
    [
        { $set: { "_masterCollectionId": <newID> } }
    ]
);

// And repeat for CollectionTwo and CollectionThree
```

Comment: It may work if CollectionOne and MasterCollection would have 1:1 relationship but the thing is that it is not the case. 

There can be two CollectionOne records that points to MasterCollection record. 
We should filter by _parentId but this is where difficulty comes.

We can easily change CollectionOne record by the parentId but in order to change CollectionTwo records we need to know parentId, same goes for CollectionThree - in order to update the records for that collection we must know all CollectionTwo ids that were updated. (it kind'a like tree stucture)

Comment: So `_masterCollectionId` doesn't point to a record in the Master Collection from `CollectionTwo` or `CollectionThree`? If that's the case, then you're right, extracting all records associated with each `CollectionOne` record is the way to go. You could make use of lodash to reformat the data in a way that means you can just run an `updateMany()` on each of the collections using an array of _ids